# Is there a way to get the generated HTML as a String from a UIComponent object?

Tags: jsf, jsfunit

I have a [UIComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) object. I would like to get the HTML code generated by this component at runtime so I can analyze it.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I am trying to use JsfUnit to create automated tests. I can get ahold of the UICompoment objects from within the test methods. However, I couldn't find a way to check the Html generated by the component.

Comment: Do you want to analyze it manually? If so then just inspect the html from your browser using for example Firebug; If not, then - what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @dratewka, I have improved my question so you can understand what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do the same what JSF does under the covers: invoke [`UIComponent#encodeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#encodeAll%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29). To capture the output, set the response writer to a local buffer by [`FacesContext#setResponseWriter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#setResponseWriter%28javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter%29).

E.g. (assuming that you're sitting in invoke application phase; when sitting in render response phase, this needs to be done differently):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ResponseWriter originalWriter = context.getResponseWriter();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

try {
    context.setResponseWriter(context.getRenderKit().createResponseWriter(writer, "text/html", "UTF-8"));
    component.encodeAll(context);
} finally {
    if (originalWriter != null) {
        context.setResponseWriter(originalWriter);
    }
}

String output = writer.toString();
// ...
```

Comment: perfect BalusC! I have used this code on the test environment and it works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: great answer, as usual, thanks. Could you please elaborate on "when sitting in render response phase, this needs to be done differently"?

Answer (score 2):

Solution by BalusC to invoke [`UIComponent#encodeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#encodeAll%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29)generally works, but I had a problem with unicode characters when using utf-8 encoding. All non-ascii characters in ajax response were damaged after I modified current context's response writer.

Instead of modifying response writer on current context retrieved by [FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentInstance()), I created a wrapper over current context by extending [FacesContextWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContextWrapper.html), so that original context is left unmodified:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
FacesContext context = new FacesContextWrapper() {
    private ResponseWriter internalWriter = getWrapped()
        .getRenderKit().createResponseWriter(writer, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    @Override
    public FacesContext getWrapped() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseWriter getResponseWriter() {
        return internalWriter;
    }

};

component.encodeAll(context);
String output = writer.toString();
```