# How to create a UIComponent instance from a String containing jsf tags?

Tags: jsf, interpreter

How to programmatically interpret jsf tags?

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
String xhtml = "<h:link value='Home' outcome='index' />";
String html = Interpreter.interpret(xhtml);
System.out.println(html);
```

And see this result:

```
<a href=".../index.xhtml">Home</a>
```

Possibly being able to pass a whole `xhtml` file as argument.

Since it's possible to [render `UIComponent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001901/3527769), how to create a `UIComponent` instance from a String containing jsf tags? In particular, what component represents a whole xhtml document?

Comment: Do you want to develop your own parser?

Comment: possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/16965229/957654

Comment: @Tiny No, I just want to be sure that html I create from java code is the same it would be if interpreted from an xhtml file (same structure, classes, etc...)

Comment: If so... just check the view code in browser when generated....

Comment: @Amrola Ok, so in my case the question reduces to: How to create a `UIComponent` instance from a `String` containing jsf tags? In particular, what component represents a whole `xhtml` document?

Comment: @JordiCastilla Hard-coding html is not a dynamic solution. What if I want to change theme or lirbary or something else?

Comment: jsf is prepared to adapt you to themes and `css` in the `xhtml` views... also you can fill the view fields with database or entity values, so I can't understand why harcoding it in a `java` class and not in a `xhtml` wiew...

Comment: update your question

Comment: @JordiCastilla I'm perfectly fine in writing one more xhtml file but I still need to be able to render it from server-side code so the question remains unanswered

Comment: Why dont you use `rendered` attribute for mentioned part and use server side code to toggle the boolean whenever necessary?

Comment: @dogiordano read the possible duplicate then...

Comment: @johny It's not what I want. Let's say, for example, I want to send an email with a style resembling that of my site. I need the html generated from an interpreter in my Java code. I'm not looking for an alterntive: I think there are many cases in which it's reasonable to want that.

Comment: @JordiCastilla I did and I updated my question accordingly

Comment: Now I am completely confused with your use case. Why would you want to send an email in such a complex fashion?

Comment: @johny Imagine I want to send a link for account activation in a confirmation email. I don't want the link to be hardcoded. I'd like to be able to specify the `outcome` attribute (and probably `<f:param>` too) for the `<h:link>` tag and let jsf calculate the correct address.