# Is there a way to get the generated HTML as a String from a UIComponent object AND bind all ajax listeners properly in RENDER response phase?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

It's a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965229/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-generated-html-as-a-string-from-a-uicomponent-object).

### Environment

Primefaces 8.0.RC3
JSF 2.2.15
Tomcat 8.5.47

### Background

I have a custom JSF component that extends `UIComponentBase`.

```
public final class Map extends UIComponentBase implements Widget {
    // resolveWidgetVar
    // a constructor
    // getters/setters
}
```

There is `MapRenderer` which will be rendering that component.

```
public final class MapRenderer extends CoreRenderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        final Map map = (Map) component;

        encodeMarkup(context, map);
        encodeScript(context, map);
    }

    private void encodeMarkup(FacesContext context, Map map) throws IOException {
        // renders a div
    }

    private void encodeScript(FacesContext context, Map map) throws IOException {
        // renders a script with PF.cw(widgetName, widgetVar, cfg)
    }

}
```

It's going to be a [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/)-based map with a legend defined as a `SelectManyMenu` component. The legend serves as both a legend and a filter. The challenge is to nicely pass everything needed to the JS side. For that, I employ the approach shown by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001901/4922375) - I basically encode a programmatically created `SelectManyMenu` to my `Writer`.

Then, I split it into 2 parts (because of the way controls (here, legends) should be defined - see the function below):

1. a JS snippet `executeInteractiveLegendScript` (with a line to create a Primefaces widget) and
2. an HTML snippet `getInteractiveLegendHTML` (a markup of the menu).

---

```
function (configuration) {
    var interactiveLegend = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});

    interactiveLegend.onAdd = function () {
        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'interactive-legend');
        container.innerHTML = configuration['getInteractiveLegendHTML']();
        return container;
    };

    interactiveLegend.addTo(map);
    configuration['executeInteractiveLegendScript']();
}
```

`configuration` is an object I have compiled on the Java side. At some point, by means of JS, I add the legend to the map. The JS snippet is being executed correctly, the Primefaces element is being displayed correctly - no problems here.

### Problem

The problem is in defining client behaviours for this programmatically created component.

```
// while rendering the map

SelectManyMenu selectManyMenu = (SelectManyMenu) context.getApplication()
    .createComponent(SelectManyMenu.COMPONENT_TYPE);

// setting children and properies
selectManyMenu.addClientBehavior("change", createAjax(context));

selectManyMenu.encodeAll(context);
```

The method to create a `ClientBehavior` is defined as follows

```
private ClientBehavior createAjax(FacesContext context) {
    Application application = context.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = application.getExpressionFactory();
    AjaxBehavior behavior = (AjaxBehavior) application.createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);

    MethodExpression methodExpression = expressionFactory.createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{myexpression}", Void.TYPE, new Class[]{String.class});
    AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl listener = new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(methodExpression, methodExpression, methodExpression);

    behavior.setProcess("@this");

    // PROBLEM HERE - this listener never gets invoked
    behavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(listener);

    return behavior;
}
```

I doubt the place where I register this client behaviour, could it be that it's too late and the listener simply doesn't get registered properly?

The question is how to make it work, and where should I create a menu instance and bind all the properties/listeners.

@BalusC, [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001901/4922375), mentioned

> (assuming that you're sitting in invoke application phase; when sitting in render response phase, this needs to be done differently):

which confirms I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I fail to see the actual usecase for which you think this approach is the problem? It feels 'hacky'. Off-topic: begging (asking) for help in a comment is not appreciated...

Comment: @Kukeltje It's hacky and dirty. I just couldn't come up with a better approach to implement this.

Comment: But if your actual usecase is not clear, we cannot help to see what the better approach would be.

Comment: @Kukeltje could you elaborate on what exactly is unclear? I tried to be as specific as possible.  The ajax listener never gets invoked because it was probably registered at the wrong place

Comment: Using a selectOneMenu as a legend AND a filter... As a filter is clear, as a legend totally not you only see one thing until you open it. A selectOneRadio would be 'clearer in that regard. So everything before your technical issue of the 'splitting into two', adding to the map etc... What do you want to achieve on a ui-design level. And what part of the technical problem is 'leaflet' related? Or is the tag applied just because you use it?

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry, I mentioned `SelectManyMenu` (this one - https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyMenu.xhtml)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208135/discussion-between-kukeltje-and-andrew-tobilko).